# Printing the first value in an array instead of just the first letter? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I have used Python to append data from an SQLite3 database to an array. Now that I have an array, I am trying to print the appended data in a format along the lines of:

```
print "Team: " + new_array[0][0] + " Score: " + new_array[0][1] + " Overall: " + new_array[0][2]
```

The code I have already would be okay for this. However, I am trying to create a loop using a counter that would print all of the data from the array in the above format.

The problem is that when I try to create a for loop and print the first value in the array, only the first letter of the value is printed. For example:

```
    print new_array[0]
```

... would print:

```
    team_6
    team_3
    team_5
    team_1
    team_2
    team_4
```

... and...

```
    print new_array[0][0]
```

... would print:

```
    t
    t
    t
    t
    t
    t
```

This is what I have so far:
        import sqlite3

```
    new_array = []

    conn = sqlite3.connect('league.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    game = c.execute("SELECT Team,Score,Overall FROM League ORDER BY Overall DESC")
    for items in game:
        new_array.append(items)

    print new_array[0][0]
```

The code above will print out 'team_6' as it should. However, the problem of printing 't's only occurs when I create a for loop.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. You say that `print new_array[0][0]` would print six T's. Is that what you _want_ it to do but it's not doing that; or is that what it _is_ doing and you don't want it to do that?

Comment: Sorry about that. What I mean is when I run:
        print new_array[0][0]
... without a for loop, it will print 'team_6'. But when I create a for loop and then print new_array[0][0] it will print 6 't's.

Comment: I don't suppose you could simplify your example a little bit so it just uses a pre-made list of strings, rather than having to use sqlite to populate it. Needless to say, we don't have a League table, so we can't run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get expected output

```
for items in game.fetchall():
    print items[0] # should be `team6` and so on
```

If you want to put in array.Do like this

```
for items in game.fetchall():
    new_array.append(items)

>>>new_array[0][0]
'team6'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the value you're looping over. You think `new_array[0][0]` is a word, but in fact `new_array[0]` is the word and `[0][0]` is the first char in that word. So if you want to print the word instead of only the first letter, just use `new_array[0]`

Answer (score 1):

The way you made your array has become a string. use `append()` like the following

```
a = list();
a.append(items); # these will be your string elements

print(a[0]) # will print your first item
```

Comment: This is close. It's still producing 6 of the same output, however. Printing a[0][0] will give an output of...
'code'(
        team_6
        team_6
        team_6
        team_6
        team_6
        team_6)

And printing a[0][0][0] will output...
'code'(
        t
        t
        t
        t
        t
        t)

Any idea on how I could print the whole team name on it's own in a for loop?

This is what I last tried:
'code'(
        for items in a:
         print a[0][0][0])